# downgrade android OS 1.6 to 1.5

Tags: android, version, operating-system, downgrade

Hi i have HTC dev phone with Firmware 1.6 now i want to downgrade to 1.5.

i follow steps which are given in this link

http://androidandme.com/2009/10/beginners/guides/how-to-manually-install-the-official-t-mobile-android-1-6-on-your-g1/

but not get any result any one have solution for it than share here to downgrade Android os version.

Comment: This isn't a programming question - try Force Close or Super User.

Answer (score 0):

You can always flash an older version of Android. Just get a compatible image and flash it the same way you did for the 1.6 update.

Comment: thanks for your answer can you send me the link for image for 1.5,
i found some of the image which aborting the installation.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to downgrade use droidfix lab tool to downgrade your android version its on playstore.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).